# No query results for model laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I make a product about multi network.
I have a daily cronjob to automatically generate invoices for networks and I create queues to generate those invoices. But I only successfully generated an invoice for the first network and the other networks all got an error and got the failed job table with the error "Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model" and I have not found a solution. solve this problem. Please help me. thanks you